# How to determine if a point is existing in only one polygon not in adjacent/other nearby polygon?

Tags: php, geojson, geofencing, point-in-polygon

I am using an algorithm given here(many others are also using It). But in my scenario for some specific point, it is showing intersections at more than one polygons.

I am using php and imported geojson in mysql. and using below code from
https://assemblysys.com/php-point-in-polygon-algorithm/

```
<?php
/*
Description: The point-in-polygon algorithm allows you to check if a point is
inside a polygon or outside of it.
Author: Michaël Niessen (2009)
Website: http://AssemblySys.com

If you find this script useful, you can show your
appreciation by getting Michaël a cup of coffee ;)
PayPal: https://www.paypal.me/MichaelNiessen

As long as this notice (including author name and details) is included and
UNALTERED, this code is licensed under the GNU General Public License version 3:
http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
*/

class pointLocation {
    var $pointOnVertex = true; // Check if the point sits exactly on one of the vertices?

    function pointLocation() {
    }

    function pointInPolygon($point, $polygon, $pointOnVertex = true) {
        $this->pointOnVertex = $pointOnVertex;

        // Transform string coordinates into arrays with x and y values
        $point = $this->pointStringToCoordinates($point);
        $vertices = array(); 
        foreach ($polygon as $vertex) {
            $vertices[] = $this->pointStringToCoordinates($vertex); 
        }

        // Check if the point sits exactly on a vertex
        if ($this->pointOnVertex == true and $this->pointOnVertex($point, $vertices) == true) {
            return "vertex";
        }

        // Check if the point is inside the polygon or on the boundary
        $intersections = 0; 
        $vertices_count = count($vertices);

        for ($i=1; $i < $vertices_count; $i++) {
            $vertex1 = $vertices[$i-1]; 
            $vertex2 = $vertices[$i];
            if ($vertex1['y'] == $vertex2['y'] and $vertex1['y'] == $point['y'] and $point['x'] > min($vertex1['x'], $vertex2['x']) and $point['x'] < max($vertex1['x'], $vertex2['x'])) { // Check if point is on an horizontal polygon boundary
                return "boundary";
            }
            if ($point['y'] > min($vertex1['y'], $vertex2['y']) and $point['y'] <= max($vertex1['y'], $vertex2['y']) and $point['x'] <= max($vertex1['x'], $vertex2['x']) and $vertex1['y'] != $vertex2['y']) { 
                $xinters = ($point['y'] - $vertex1['y']) * ($vertex2['x'] - $vertex1['x']) / ($vertex2['y'] - $vertex1['y']) + $vertex1['x']; 
                if ($xinters == $point['x']) { // Check if point is on the polygon boundary (other than horizontal)
                    return "boundary";
                }
                if ($vertex1['x'] == $vertex2['x'] || $point['x'] <= $xinters) {
                    $intersections++; 
                }
            } 
        } 
        // If the number of edges we passed through is odd, then it's in the polygon. 
        if ($intersections % 2 != 0) {
            return "inside";
        } else {
            return "outside";
        }
    }

    function pointOnVertex($point, $vertices) {
        foreach($vertices as $vertex) {
            if ($point == $vertex) {
                return true;
            }
        }

    }

    function pointStringToCoordinates($pointString) {
        $coordinates = explode(" ", $pointString);
        return array("x" => $coordinates[0], "y" => $coordinates[1]);
    }

}
?>
```

above code is working fine for most of the point but in some cases, it is returning that the given point exists in more than one polygons(plotted them and they are 80 km for).
so my doubts are.
1- am I using right algo for my problem?
2- what is the purpose of below lines in the above code?

```
$xinters = ($point['y'] - $vertex1['y']) * ($vertex2['x'] - $vertex1['x']) / ($vertex2['y'] - $vertex1['y']) + $vertex1['x'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question.
As I did not get any solid solution, I had to come up with a workaround.
I subtracted point[x] from xinters, put them in an array and picked shortest one. this makes sure that the intersected polygon is the one that I was looking for.